# Laravel Backpack enableAjaxTable does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I got the following error upgrading from Laravel Backpack 3.6 to 4.0.

> BadMethodCallException Method
> Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanel::enableAjaxTable does
> not exist.

[image: [enter image description here]]

Comment: Please, [don't post your code/error messages as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4298200). Firstly we want to copy/paste it, and secondly, search engines cannot index that information. So please make sure that any textual information is actually provided in text form.

Answer (score 1):

Starting in Laravel Backpack 3.4 it defaulted to using Ajax on all CRUD controllers, but allowed you to disable it and keep the legacy format (though you also had to use the old views for that). Starting Backpack 4.0 you can no longer choose, and everything automatically loads via Ajax. Therefore the call to use ajax tables is no longer necessary and you can just remove the call altogether